Ubuntu 24 Plymouth splash during shutdown has corrupted text
Environment: Ubuntu 24.04, kernel Linux 6.10.9-1-t2-noble, wayland, amdgpu, AMD Radeon™ Pro 580X, mesa driver, MacPro 7,1.
At shutdown if I want to show the non-quiet splash and select "Esc" key I see corrupted text in every line similar to:
Font characters displayed as squares in Ubuntu 18.04
Trying to reset font cache next.
That didn't work.

is there any thing unusual about your initrd? In my case, I have added dropbear to it.

I see this too. Here is a screen shot.
Plymouth is somehow causing this.
The best workaround in my opinion is to change the plymouth theme to to a text theme.
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth 100

sudo update-alternatives --set default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-text/ubuntu-text.plymouth

sudo update-initramfs -u

this makes the login process not too ugly and I don't get the systemd rendering errors.
*** UPDATE ***
I think this is a race condition. At some point in the shutdown, the file system disappears, and resources must be in RAM.
This was discovered by the Ubuntu developers a few years ago.
The fix was to display a blank message before the file system disappears, so that the font resources are loaded into ram. But this display message is a async command sent to the plymouth background daemon and perhaps it is not executed in time on all hardware. So I experimented with adding a delay. 1s worked most of the time but not all of the time, so I'm using 2s now. This is obviously ridiculous, how can it take so long, but anyway.
You can try this:
sudo vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/plymouth-switch-root-initramfs.service 

I made a change to add a 2s sleep:
[Unit]
Description=Tell Plymouth To Jump To initramfs
DefaultDependencies=no
# dracut-shutdown.service restores the initramfs when it is _stopped_
# use Conflicts to make sure its ExecStop has run before we do
Conflicts=dracut-shutdown.service
After=plymouth-halt.service plymouth-reboot.service plymouth-poweroff.service plymouth-kexec.service dracut-shutdown.service mkinitcpio-generate-shutdown-ramfs.service
ConditionPathExists=|/run/initramfs/bin/sh
ConditionPathExists=|/run/initramfs/shutdown

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
# Emit a blank message to force a dynamic load of all graphics libraries
# required for rendering text since it's a non-trivially large set, too large
# to manage manually in the initramfs. This will allow casper to render text
# like the live media ejection message after the jump...
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/plymouth message --text="Preload graphics libraries..."
ExecStart=-/bin/sleep 2
ExecStart=-/usr/bin/plymouth update-root-fs --new-root-dir=/run/initramfs

Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes

check the theme:
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
the bgrt.plymouth is the default theme

Hi Tim, that makes the text look better! Thanks for the suggestion. I am surprised this bug hasn't come up much, or anybody has complained about it.

I just added what is for me a better fix, it allows the default theme  to work. I have reported this finding to the bug report.

Interestingly while that works it appears plymouth ignores or does not use any fractional scale setting 150% and/or gdm3 interface scaling setting (which does not support fractional scaling) at 200%. How can you get plymouth on high dpi screens to use 200% scale?

@TimRichardson could you please provide a link to the bug report you're referring to?

Some relevant bug reports: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/plymouth/plymouth/-/issues/152  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/plymouth/+bug/2056526
Status of this is the even with large delay (2s) this apparent race condition would still happen sometimes. It was so annoying and impenetrable that I have removed plymouth on my workstation. I don't know what happens on shutdown ... all my reading said for for Debian/Ubuntu the initramfs is used but why some fonts are sometimes not available is a mystery to me still, something to do with the removal of the initfamfs in shutdown I think.

also: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/plymouth/plymouth/-/merge_requests/336
